# Saving CheckedTextView state

Tags: android-listview, checkedtextview

I have a list consisting of CheckedTextViews in one Activity'A'. I want the checked items to b in the same state, when I press backbutton of activity 'A' and come to the same activity'A'. Can anyone help? I am new to android .

Answer (score 0):

you can use startActivityForResult method for start ActivityB and override onActivityResult in ActivityA for send state from B to A same below

Step 1

When starting Activity 2  use startActivityForResult. This allows you handle the result in the calling activity.

```
startActivityForResult(MY_REQUEST_ID);
```

Step 2

In Activities 2 call setResult(int, Intent) to return a value:

```
Intent resultData = new Intent();
resultData.putExtra("valueName", "valueData");//you can set state in here
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
finish();
```

Step 3

In your calling activty, implement onActivityResult and get the data:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
          Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_ID) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String myValue = data.getStringExtra("valueName"); //you can get state here
            // use 'myValue' return value here
          }
      }
}
```